# Replacing the pipe in the double quoted csv file with comma using awk command

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have data which contains the pipe in it and I want to replace these pipe with comma. below is the data sample

```
"PT3QB789TSUIDF371261","THE TORONTO|DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW| ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS|CA.ON.OSC|ASIC*|AAAA"
"PT3QB789TSUIDF371261","ABC|XYZ|123","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS|CA.ON.OSC|ASIC*"
```

My output should look like as

```
"PT3QB789TSUIDF371261","THE TORONTO,DOMINION BANK","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW, ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*,AAAA"
"PT3QB789TSUIDF371261","ABC,XYZ,123","2016-05-24T00:36:42Z","ANZ BANK NEW ZEALAND LIMITED","HZSN7FQBPO5IEWYIGC72","MAS,CA.ON.OSC,ASIC*"
```

I tried the below command which did not work for me

```
awk -F"\"" 'BEGIN{OFS="\""}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){ if(i%2==0) gsub(/|/, ",", $i)}} {print $0}' file
```

Comment: a simple `sed 's/|/,/g' file` will do for given sample.. any other reason why you are using `awk`?

Comment: one issue with your command is `/|/` ... `|` is a meta character, so it should be `/\|/`

Comment: Why? That'll just make your file MUCH harder to do anything else with afterwards with command line tools as they'll then need additional logic to distinguish commas within fields from commas between fields.

Answer (score 0):

if you can chose not to use awk then you can try this -

sed -i 's/theOriginalChar/theNewChar/g' theFile.txt

if you have to use awk-
notice that the vertical bar (|) allows regular expressions
so to use | in your example you need to add \ before the |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change ALL pipes to commas, either sed:

```
sed -i 's/|/,/g' file.txt
```

or tr:

```
tr \| , < file.txt > file1.txt
```

But... if you really want to use awk I'd try something like this (cannot test it right now):

```
awk -F\| 'BEGIN{OFS=","} {$1=$1; print}' file.txt > file1.txt
```